# How to find out radius of curvature by knowing velocity and angle with horizontal of a body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle moving in air with initial velocity 100 m/s making an angle 60 degree with horizontal then how to calculate radius of curvature at time equals to one second ??

Comment: Hi Jitheesh and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Is the particle moving above the horizontal or below the horizontal?

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Comment: above the horizontal

Comment: I just need the method only